# How to populate data using Angular framework in my case?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using angular and trying to create a pagination feature.

I have something like

Angular controller

```
appModule.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
   $scope.numbers = 7;
}])
```

html:

```
 <button ng-repeat=' not sure what to do here'>{{number.days}}</button>
//display more buttons...
```

The button texts will be something like 1, 2, 3,4… depends on the total page we have from the data.

I am not sure how to accomplish this. can anyone help me about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` only works with collections, so you would have to define `$scope.numbers=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and then do:
 `<button ng-repeat='number in numbers'>{{number}}</button>`

or, you could use a function that returns an array
`<button ng-repeat='i in buildNumbers( number )'></button>` where `number` is defined on the scope like `$scope.number = 7` and `buildNumber` converts the number to an array.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) - an angular high-performant data grid for rendering rows and really shines when you have lots of rows, it has a lot of nice features like filtering, sorting and of-course pagination.

**Example:**

html:

```
 <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</body>
```

js:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.filterOptions = {
        filterText: "",
        useExternalFilter: true
    }; 
    $scope.totalServerItems = 0;
    $scope.pagingOptions = {
        pageSizes: [250, 500, 1000],
        pageSize: 250,
        currentPage: 1
    };  
    $scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){  
        var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
        $scope.myData = pagedData;
        $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
        if (!$scope.$$phase) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    };
    $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var data;
            if (searchText) {
                var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
                $http.get('jsonFiles/largeLoad.json').success(function (largeLoad) {        
                    data = largeLoad.filter(function(item) {
                        return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                    });
                    $scope.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);
                });            
            } else {
                $http.get('jsonFiles/largeLoad.json').success(function (largeLoad) {
                    $scope.setPagingData(largeLoad,page,pageSize);
                });
            }
        }, 100);
    };

    $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);

    $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
          $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
        }
    }, true);
    $scope.$watch('filterOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
          $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
        }
    }, true);

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        enablePaging: true,
        showFooter: true,
        totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
        pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
        filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions
    };
});
```

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/luDhRf?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

There are the [Tutorials](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) which will show you how to use AngularJS and the ng-repeat.  Then, if you [combine Bootstrap pagination](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination) you can achieve what you want quite easily

In your Controller:

```
App.controller('PageCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.pages = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
}
```

In the HTML:

```
<ul class="pagination" ng-repeat="page in pages">
    <li><a href="#/Page{{page}}">{{page}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like the solution but I need to customize my page button. I don't think I can do that with bootstrap. +1 though

Comment: @Links  What do you mean by customize the button?  You can change the HTML code in the <li>, <a>, etc to be buttons if needed.  You could also use a function to return information instead of this simple repeat.